# Running Supervisord on a Mac

Tags: mac-osx, python, supervisord

I'm trying to get it supervisord running on my Mac. The instructions call for using a $BINDIR path variable and I can't figure out what that should be. I tried using the directory I got from `$ which python`, which = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/, but when I use that I get an error:

`$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/supervisord: No such file or directory`

From the docs:

> This section makes reference to a BINDIR when explaining how to run
>   the supervisord and supervisorctl commands. This is the “bindir”
>   directory that your Python installation has been configured with. For
>   example, for an installation of Python installed via ./configure
>   --prefix=/usr/local/py; make; make install, BINDIR would be /usr/local/py/bin. Python interpreters on different platforms use a
>   different BINDIR. Look at the output of setup.py install if you can’t
>   figure out where yours is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed `supervisord` yet? If not, it would be a good idea to create a virtual environment and then install into that. With a virtual environment, it doesn't matter so much where you put tools (especially when you are trying them out) and you don't get piles of conflicting libraries all installed in the same place.

If you haven't installed anything at all yet, I would suggest:

- [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to provide the base tools
- [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/) via `brew virtualenv`
- Create a virtual environment for `supervisord`: `virtualenv supe`
- Activate it: `cd supe; . bin/activate  ##note the dot, it matters`
- Install supervisord using pip: `pip install supervisord`

Comment: khoxsey- Thanks- I ended up finding supervisord in /usr/local/bin/ - but prob good advice on virtualenv. Though why would I need to install supervisord *into* a virtualenv? Can't virtualenvs be created anytime, unrelated to where things are installed?

Comment: The best reason to install supervisord into a virtualenv rather than in the system python is to control the runtime environment. In your case, you have no control over what Apple does with the OSX system python, so a venv allows you to control what is in, and what is out. But you're right, it is a personal preference.

Comment: supervisor is installed without the d in the pip install command